# How can I display the value of an attribute in list.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, attributes

I have this attribute
[image]

**CODE PHP:**

```
  $attributeCode = 'product_text';

                if ($_product->getData($attributeCode) !== null){
                    echo $_product->getAttributeText($attributeCode);
                }else{
                    echo 'Is NULL';
                }
```

The problem is I get NULL for each product and I can not display the value of the attribute.

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcLyC.png)

Comment: Have you got solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_product->getData($attributeCode) !== null){

                    echo $_product->getData($attributeCode);
                }else{

                    echo 'Is NULL';
                }
```

Syntax:

```
echo $_product->getData('attribute_code');

echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code'); // in case of dropdown
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$attributeCode = 'product_text';
if ($_product->getData($attributeCode) != null)
{
    echo $_product->getProductText();
}
else
{
    echo 'Is NULL';
}
```

Also set one more field value to yes, follow this screen-shot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First when you set this config `Used in product list` , you should **reindex all** and **clear the cache**

Then you can use `$_product->getAttributeText('my_attribute');`